# nameservers reported by whois cannot be found by nslookup

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, dns-zone, nslookup, whois

The nameservers of my domain are listed correctly on the whois entry:

```
whois destiglobal.com | grep NS
```

gives the following result:

```
Name Server: HEATHER.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
Name Server: OWEN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
```

but a nameserver search with dig does not return anything:

```
dig +search +short NS destiglobal.com
```

I was looking at [this querstion](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60965/what-does-it-mean-when-the-nameservers-reported-by-whois-do-not-match-those-repo) which described a similar issue and the hint in this question was the problem might be that no authoritive answer for my domain lookup exists:

so I investigated further to trace back the DNS resultion path using dig trace:

```
dig +trace destiglobal.com  

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +trace destiglobal.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           427432  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           427432  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
;; Received 811 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 11 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            86400   IN  DS  30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.            86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20180423170000 20180410160000 39570 . YDhqBnGqUMqkWRz6hPQB4lhfX6A73qsKQBi4a+ZzkbSUhwtc1T/RmViI e7P8nl+Z3lsKD8+AhBN3V/7JDeriNSK6+nq6U1zq5iGP/kEw86BFA8L2 oBY8czheCNkilLWSfCYzHz726R69fNUMW6ajp0lGeGAr8J9brM/01set yUJQvVvJWc73d5cnbs7y2eiUgGh939SqGnLl4b+1dwswRlKt5lMYIdv5 WiQUbHecvtvMvg/PT6xlR91kHTh1ON3DUFeZFXOdwtfq9ehNoOuvWutG HERT2VbEx1XY/p7A1y3BeTXAW1M7N0iDolkHKc2qslN22nkn0pUnB1QC yKPiig==
;; Received 1175 bytes from 2001:500:1::53#53(h.root-servers.net) in 163 ms

com.            900 IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1523441761 1800 900 604800 86400
com.            900 IN  RRSIG   SOA 8 1 900 20180418101601 20180411090601 46967 com. gWGmFMc7JcV66HRPf5rC/6qbV38K18q4O4i6TeUjHIQYyXSE4G6xncl+ CTcsj4I5jDszxM/8izmhwrHpRz4Fxs/BsFyUbViSKbRbYbzrA+Pu9ma+ N5fAFT+BvTY01tx2luu3qKFQLa8pMfW9HjUTLVAvvh9zPFNpRrLBA3jX Kmo=
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20180418044729 20180411033729 46967 com. k9ZhhJ/HGc6o2LJBpzYkMlOhkw2tYNoP85bUnifUBGOLojGB7nHOmiv6 ozeiL5Cnyz070tWmbyz0CYvhX78CrrObOt9DjTmSe9019GVBHYrqXk/7 9zXoJu+s3DdD1PaJUexgE91ducHmYhXF0618GQX3/xYZn3xmcUgjIjGK mCw=
0G3KEATRSRVKUADEK0SQM4UT7GO0B0NK.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - 0G3LK864G8GRULBC1RUEGK0RT2PFRHA3 NS DS RRSIG
0G3KEATRSRVKUADEK0SQM4UT7GO0B0NK.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20180417050536 20180410035536 46967 com. jwFRmb77tWyVgdZuKIiud8zz31sthpmpqbTNvbQBsjEXHh7u3kesE6xN zEuNJ1YrvAOaEW2TLX/M0geOv1LgnEqkI7CjdrRZECIvgkekDRZmWyUz hJQCoktkNn+7vwxn7/WCyPWiiZ/Xdh0p9+z12aY6tPdxGXe+q3F9ZvOK QRw=
3RL20VCNK6KV8OT9TDIJPI0JU1SS6ONS.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - 3RL3ODP8D910939I655B97GAQU6VE1Q7 NS DS RRSIG
3RL20VCNK6KV8OT9TDIJPI0JU1SS6ONS.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20180415042450 20180408031450 46967 com. IhbnQXIq5RlG9CMXhBshx052OWd4vCgXfJdqqNjJgS3iWDJXpv1KFsy1 W8fCqrqXvU2TkpCosVmM1fUViUwVVJGABZKHVttYdjpy2pnYh26xMSVF MwwvBO3yRDeNrhPRd1Ktel8Pue1SJ4G8mdwbVAKnwrQy3fhLcDfudIQf FRs=
;; Received 1007 bytes from 2001:503:d414::30#53(f.gtld-servers.net) in 41 ms
```

according to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C22bQ.png) and [this](https://ns1.com/articles/using-dig-trace) explanaiton of dig trace the domain resolves up until step 3 (root server back to recursive resolver) and fails at step 4 (recursive resolver to authorative servers)

Is my assumption that there are no authorative nameservers set for my domain correct?
And if so what could I/should I do to resolve this issue?

I have pointed my nameservers to cloudflare on my hosting provider (I do not have access to the zone files on my hosting provider and want to manage DNS through cloudflare on my domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of your problem can be found from this line in your whoisdb information:

```
Domain Status: clientHold https://icann.org/epp#clientHold
```

> This status code tells your domain's registry to not activate your
>   domain in the DNS and as a consequence, it will not resolve. It is an
>   uncommon status that is usually enacted during legal disputes,
>   non-payment, or when your domain is subject to deletion.
>
> Often, this status indicates an issue with your domain that needs resolution. If so, you should contact your registrar to resolve the issue. If your domain does not have any issues, but you need it to resolve, you must first contact your registrar and request that they remove this status code.

This leads to the fact, that zone `com` returns `NXDOMAIN` for `destiglobal.com`. This is not a technical problem; it's likely a legal or contract problem, so you need to contact the registrar.

From technical point of view I can't see any other error. Your authoritative nameservers are both configured fine, confirmed by directly querying from them for `A`, `NS` and `SOA` – all coherent:

```
$ dig destiglobal.com @heather.ns.cloudflare.com +short
$ dig destiglobal.com @owen.ns.cloudflare.com  +short
54.154.220.247

$ dig destiglobal.com SOA @heather.ns.cloudflare.com +short
$ dig destiglobal.com SOA @owen.ns.cloudflare.com +short
heather.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2027493360 10000 2400 604800 3600

$ dig destiglobal.com NS @heather.ns.cloudflare.com +short
$ dig destiglobal.com NS @owen.ns.cloudflare.com +short
heather.ns.cloudflare.com.
owen.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

And all this matches the information in the whois database:

```
Domain Name: DESTIGLOBAL.COM 
Name Server: HEATHER.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
Name Server: OWEN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
```

Once you get things clear with the registrar, this should work fine, probably within 24-48 hours.

Comment: thank you very much for this analysis I will contact my registrar and resolve this issue with them. you saved my day thank you! :)